# Adding specific route to my IP camera through eth0 wont work, but adding a range will

Tags: networking, routing, ip

I have an IP camera configured to always use the IP `192.168.1.37` connected through ethernet to my raspberry pi. I'm also connected to the raspberry pi, through wifi.

If I do:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ip address add 192.168.1.133/24 dev eth0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.25.1    0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-b5bfd2d20c0b
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-025a6abb31ab
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.25.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

then by doing `wget 192.168.1.37` I reach my camera page.

However, if I simply add the specific route to 192.168.1.37, like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.25.1    0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-b5bfd2d20c0b
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-025a6abb31ab
192.168.1.37    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.25.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

Then wget `192.168.1.37` hags forever. That is, I can't access my camera.

Why is it that when I add a range of IPs to `eth0` I can find my camera, but when I add just the specific IP, I can't?

ps: I discovered the `sudo ip address add 192.168.1.133/24 dev eth0` trick somewhere and have been using since then, but now I want to learn what's happening and tried to add a specific route to the camera IP just to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ip address add 192.168.1.133/24 dev eth0` this command also add a route `192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0` to all devices with ip 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254 connected to lan over eth0. After that you can connect from 192.168.1.133 to 192.168.1.37
You can't make local connection if you just make a route and don't configure ip address.

Comment: It doesn't makes sense. In the first case, it adds a route for each device (1 to 254). In the second case it just adds a route for the specific device I want. In both cases it should work. Unless `ip address add` also does another thing. What is it? What you mean when you say 'configure ip address'?

Comment: I tried this: `sudo ip address add 192.168.1.133 dev eth0` and then `sudo route add -host 192.168.1.37 dev eth0`. Why didn't this work either? `eth0` now has the IP and there's a specific route for the camera

Comment: when you make `ip address add 192.168.1.133 dev eth0` you didn't specify mask. So mask must be 32 => no local connect to 192.168.1.0 except 192.168.1.133

Comment: When I do `sudo ip address add 192.168.1.133/32 dev eth0` I see nothing about `eth0` on `route -n`

Comment: That was my fault. I meant that `ip address add 192.168.1.133 dev eth0` = `ip address add 192.168.1.133/32 dev eth0`. Mask 32 make no route because this lan has only 1 ip. And mask 24 has route because there are 253 posible hosts. Use some lan calculator to anderstand lan adressing.